# stoppApp on pressing Action Button

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying my hands on some simply Shiny apps to display my data. As a first example I'm trying to figure out how to deal with data input and buttons.

In the below code I am able to adjust the values I want and get the output updated when I hit the submit button. However, I am unable to quick the app when I hit the action button. I looked up the tutorials/help pages and I thought the code `observeEvent( input$action, { stopApp() } )` should stop the shiny app upon a click of the button. But it's not doing anything. Likewise I found `if (input$action == 1) stopApp( )` but that doesn't do anything either.

I have two questions: 1) How do I properly write that line so the app stops executing and continues at `# next steps`? 2) How do I alter the code so that the sliders are continuously monitor and the results updated so that there is no need to hit the submit button.?

```
library(shiny)

#// Define UI for game inputs ----
ui <- fluidPage(

     #// App title ----
     titlePanel("Learn Spanish numbers"),
     
     #// What's the diff between sidebar and fluidrow
     fluidRow ( 
     
          #// Input: Sliders for the number of guesses and range ----
          
          #// column width and title
          column(10, h3("Let's play a game!"),
                
               #// Input: Slider1 for the number of guesses ---- 
               sliderInput("number",
               #// Slider title and parameters ----
               h4("How many numbers?"),  
               min = 0,
               max = 100,
               value = 50
               ), #// end slider1 input
          
                         
               #// Input: Slider2 for the range of numberesses ----  
               sliderInput("range", 
               #// Slider title and parameters ----
               h4("What range of numbers?"),
               min = 0,
               max = 100,
               value = c(25, 75)
               ), #// end slider1 input
          
               #// Input: submit button ----  
               submitButton("Submit")
               
          ), #// end column
 
          #// Column width and title for output panel ----
          column(10, h3("This is your selection!"),
          
               #// Output: Text ----
               textOutput(outputId = "out_num"),
               br(), 
               textOutput(outputId = "out_range"),
               
               #// action button: Let's play ----
               br(), 
               br(), 
               actionButton("action", "Let's Play")
          
          ) #// end column
      ) #// end fluidrow
) # end fluidpage

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) { 
 
     observeEvent( input$action, { stopApp() } ) 
      
     #// defines output for "number"
     output$out_num <- renderText({
          #// number of games
          paste("Number of games: ", input$number)
     })

     #// defines output for "number"
     output$out_range <- renderText({
          #// range of numbers
          paste("Numbers will range from ", input$range[[1]], "to", input$range[[2]] )
     })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

# next steps
```

Comment: If you replace your `submitButton` with `actionButton`, your issue #2 is resolved.  I am not clear on your issue #1.  This app stops working when you click on Let's Play button.

Comment: Please note that submit buttons do not have a value of their own, they control when the app accesses values of other widgets.  In your case, it was working as intended.  Your input got updated only when you clicked on Submit button.

Comment: @ybs thanks for your note. I’ll test some more and see based on your comments. I guess I had expected the app window to close... but maybe it just stops executing?

Comment: Oh, I see now. If I click on the action button it sets the state from 0 to 1. So then I have to click the submit button after to get the execution on the server side. Is there a way how server-side script continually checks for user-action and thus get rid of the submit button entirely?

Comment: If you remove the submit button, your code works the way you want.

Comment: :D -- awesome! I have been desperately googling action buttons, observe events, appStop, ... and it could all be solved with a single `#`. I did not realize that the mere presence of the submit button prevents the continuous evaluation of the state-changes.

Comment: The documentation for `submitButton` says that its use is "generally discouraged".